# Magento2 complicated price rendering

Tags: product, magento2, price

I just started learning Magento2. I was able to override template, assign new ones etc.

But I found it too typical to understand the price rendering. Specially after looking at the following:

```
https://mage2.pro/t/topic/352
```

Is there no way to do something like:   $_product->getPrice()

Why it is so typical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get product price with the following code:

```
$_productHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product');
$productPrice = $_productHelper->getFinalPrice($_product);
```

Comment: How can I also echo the currency with the price, so GBP 500.00 or 450 AED for LTR and RTL